# Kendo Grid data not binding correctly after refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

When I load the page, it is a partial page, the grid is populated with data

[image]

but once I call the refresh method like this

```
<button onclick="doRefresh">refresh</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doRefresh = function () {
            var kendogrid = $("#this_Id").data("kendoGrid");                 
            kendogrid.refresh();
    }
</script>
```

it should refresh the grid rebuilding it with the datasource currently bound to the Grid. But the grid becomes empty

[image]
I think I am binding the model wrong because once I refresh the grid I loose all the data. I have tried binding the model and using the bindto method as [mentioned here](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/server-binding).

Here is my view:

```
 @model List<bModel>

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("this_Id") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.Sequence).Title("Seq.");
        columns.Bound(m => m.JobType).Title("Job Type");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Service).Title("Service");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Status).Title("Status");
        columns.Bound(m => m.PropertyType).Title("Property Type");
        columns.Bound(m => m.PropertySubType).Title("Property SubType");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Address).Title("Address");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("taskTemplate")
    .DetailTemplate(
               .......
        )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Model(model => model.Id(jobItem => jobItem.Id))
    )
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetJobForBulkUpdate", "Project", new { jobId = "#=Id#" }))
    .Events(events => events.DetailExpand("detailExpand"))
)
```

And I am calling the view in panel bar like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
      .Name("panel-bar")
      .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Multiple)
      .ExpandAll(true)
      .Items(panel =>
      {       
          panel.Add()
              .Text("<span id='batch-update-panel-bar-job'>JOB-TASK</span>")
              .Encoded(false)
              .Content("<div id='update-model'>" + Html.Action("BatchUpdateJob", "BatchUpdate", new { projectId = Model.Id}).ToHtmlString() + "</div>");      
      })
)
```

and the controller method is like this

```
public ActionResult BatchUpdateJob(int projectId)
{
    mymodel = something;
    return PartialView("_MymodelPageJob", mymodel);
}

public ActionResult GetJobForBulkUpdate(int projectId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {            
           List<OfData> jobData = getData();
        return Json(jobData.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Comment: @SeanCh Sorry was busy over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**  user changed the binding to Ajax and problem was data being returned was in incorrect format.Fixing the incoming data format by following the example below of ajax format helped to solve the issue.

> once I call the refresh method like this grid becomes empty. **kendogrid.refresh();**

**use correct Html.Action not sure if your controller is being hit**

```
@Html.Action("BatchUpdateJob", "ControllerName", new { projectId = Model.Id });
```

you are *just calling refresh on the grid with no data* and of course it will show empty. So you want to auto refresh the grid based on certain **setTimeout** because destination data can be different after certain interval.

**DO NOT USE THIS !**  you are doing it in a wrong way see the documentation and clear your basics

```
    var kendogrid = $("#this_Id").data("kendoGrid");
    console.log(kendogrid.dataItem());
    kendogrid.refresh();
```

**INSTEAD USE THIS -**

```
 //read will request the server and reload only reload datasource
    $('#this_Id').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();

    //refresh will re-render items in grid from the current datasource
    $('#this_Id').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Now 
 ---- AS requested by user i am adding a sample demo for **AJAX** and **server side binding**.

***AJAX BINDING :***  as discussed here on telerik documentation [Ajax binding](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding)

**ViewModel**

```
 public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    }
```

**Grid in Razor syntax**

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoGridAjaxBinding.Models.ProductViewModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax() 
      //Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format.    
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")) 

       )
       )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(product => product.ProductID);
          columns.Bound(product => product.ProductName);
          columns.Bound(product => product.UnitsInStock);
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
)
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            using (var northwind = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                IQueryable<Product> products = northwind.Products;
                //Convert the Product entities to ProductViewModel instances.
                DataSourceResult result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request, product => new ProductViewModel
                        {
                        ProductID = product.ProductID,
                        ProductName = product.ProductName,
                        UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock
                        });
                return Json(result);
            }
        }
```

**SERVER SIDE BINDING:** as discussed here on telerik documentation [Server side binding](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/server-binding)

There are a few ways to do this:

- **Bind to the view model**
- Bind to items from ViewData or ViewBag Use the
- BindTo method Pass additional data to an action method

Here is the **github solution** that discuss the server side binding download it
and see what you are missing - [Server side binding](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/server-binding)

Comment: Calling read on the data source causes the page to reload. Which I assume should be expected since my grid uses server data binding. But that is not what I want though, since it looks like I am not binding the model correctly which is why the Grid does not have anything as it's datasource object.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I changed it to AJAX, but as i checked the datasource I do see data but calling the dataitem method returns me a null. Looking into it more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already read the server side binding page. I posted the link in my question. I do apologize for the messy code, I left some stuff out and renamed some other things since this is code for my work place.

Comment: I will fix my question.

Comment: update your question please . dont mind but please be considerate in posting since it takes time to answer

Comment: After reading it more and looking at the ajax example I got it to work. The data I was returning was wrong format too. Thanks :D